# flipping between register and login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register_link").click(function()
    {
        $("#login_or_register").empty();
        $("#login_or_register").load("register_form.php");
    });
    $("#login_link").click(function()
    {
        $("#login_or_register").empty();
        $("#login_or_register").load("login_form.php");
    });
});

</script>
```

This is my jquery code for flipping between login and register forms.
Initially the page contains the login form and a link to load the register form. It works the first time to load the register form and a link to load the login form. But it doesn't work after that. It doesn't change from register to login form. How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the listeners are only set on existing elements. When you load something using Ajax (`jQuery.load()`), there will be no listeners on those new elements. You can fix it by re-initializing the click listeners, after the new content is loaded, like this:

```
<script>
    function listenToClick() {
        $("#register_link").click(function() {
            $("#login_or_register").empty();
            $("#login_or_register").load("register_form.php", function() {
                listenToClick();
            });
        });

        $("#login_link").click(function() {
            $("#login_or_register").empty();
            $("#login_or_register").load("login_form.php", function() {
                listenToClick();
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        listenToClick();
    });
</script>
```

An even better option would be to listen to the click event using the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. The [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function also listens to future elements (the elements created by `jQuery.load()`).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#register_link").on('click', function() {
            $("#login_or_register").empty();
            $("#login_or_register").load("register_form.php");
        });

        $("#login_link").on('click', function() {
            $("#login_or_register").empty();
            $("#login_or_register").load("login_form.php");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on()` to delegate the events like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', "#register_link, #login_link", function() {
        $("#login_or_register")
            .empty()
            .load($(this).is('#register_link') ? "register_form.php" : "login_form.php");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation to account for elements that don't exist at run time that may be added to the dom later:

```
$(document).on('click', '#register_link, #login_link').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).is('#login_link') ?  "login_form.php" :"register_form.php" ;
    $("#login_or_register").empty().load(url);

});
```

Comment: You reverted the urls in the post.

Comment: @Beginner oops ..guess i did to